# what`s the meaning of {"item1","item2",...} in python2.7

Tags: python, dictionary, structure

I was confused about the structure {item1,item2,item3} in python2.7. Is it a set?

what i did :

[image: python2.7]

while

[image: python2.3]

so,what`s the meaning of {"item1","item2",...} in python2.7 ?

Comment: Heading out the door, but what you're looking at is a [Python tuple](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm)

Comment: @TemporalWolf No, this is a set.

Answer (score 4):

You can inspect the type an object with the `type()` function and figure what's going on :)

You will discover that in python2.7, `a={1, 2, 3}` is a **Set**. You might be wondering "Hey, but in python2.3 there was a set data structure as well!"

Well, the syntax was slightly different: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Therefore, in python2.7, they have added a **syntactic sugar** for creating sets.

Answer (score 0):

```
type(a)
```

Yes, it is. You can use type().